# PHP while loop omits first entry from MySQL database select

Tags: php, mysql

I have **four rows** in my table. **Only three** are shown.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

The result is `234`, but should be `1234`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This line already fetches the first entry. Thus in the `while` loop you fetch the second element.

Correctly it should be:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Alternatively:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do {
    echo $row['id'];
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Answer (score 4):

You are already advancing the query buffer one row before the loop by calling mysql_fetch_array() outside of it. Remove that call and it should work as expected